Tic-tac-toe encode them all
I decided to create a complete guide to the great game of tic-tac-toe.
I expected it to be extremely popular, so to save on paper while printing it I decided to encode all possible game positions.
I counted that there are exactly 6045 correct ways to put x and o on a \$3\times3\$ board.
EDIT: 6046, I forgot to count empty board.
A position is considered correct if the number of xs are equal to or one greater than the number of os.
Please help me write a function that accepts a position on the board and returns the encoded result.
This function should:

Accept a string consisting of exactly 9 symbols x, o or   (whitespace), where all inputs are correct positions.
It should return a string consisting of exactly 13 symbols, all of which are either 1 or 0.
The result should be unique for every board.

You can choose which encoding algorithm you want to use.

Example
The example
|x| | |
| |o|x|
|x| |o|

Corresponds to the input x   oxx o.

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer wins. All usual rules apply.

Do you confirm that we must count invalid positions such as this one? Also, with the only constraint given in the challenge, I think they are 6046 positions. Maybe you didn't count the empty board?

Consider relaxing the output to allow integers rather than binary strings. Additionally, is it your intent that any 2146 of the possible outputs can be left unmapped-to--merely "compress positions into 13 bits" rather than "enumerate all positions"?

@Arnauld yes. That position considered correct for purpose of this question.

@UnrelatedString yes. Intent it to compress. Title is bit misleading.

Can we use different characters than x, o, and space for the input?

If you discount rotations and reflections and only count incomplete positions with equal xs and os then there are 304 of those. See Matchbox Educable Noughts and Crosses Engine.

@Jordan you can replace space with other character, like -. If it really helps you can chose other symbols for x and o, but please be reasonable.

@talexmovedtoCodidact Is 0, 1, and 2 reasonable?

@Jordan I don't think so. The have no resemblance with original characters.

@Jordan it should be obvious what characters mean if you put them on the board.

Vyxal, 17 bytes
2ʀ9↔µ∑;«+⅛«İṠḟbṅḢ

Try it Online!
This relies on a couple of very nice coincidences:

Padding the output to length 13 would cost 4 bytes 13∆Z. One thing we could do to avoid this is, instead of mapping the input to the range [0, 6045], instead map it to some subset of [2^13, 2^14) or similar, resulting in 14-bit strings starting with a 1, from which we can remove the first character.
Valid boards should contain at most 1 more X than O, which is equivalent to mapping x to 1, o to -1 and   to 0, and checking if the sum is 0 (same amount) or 1 (one more x). This is equivalent to mapping o x to 012 and checking if the sum is 9 or 10.
Now for the neat part: There are 8272 boards with sum at most 8, and 5365 boards with sum at least 11. This means that, if we construct a list of all the boards and sort it by their sums, the valid boards with sums 9 and 10 will be between indices 8272 and 14317, which is within the desired 14-bit range, so all we have to do is find the index of the input in that list, convert it to binary and remove the first character.

The caveat of all this is that it's quite slow, taking 30-60 seconds on my computer. Because it's constructing a list of every board, it takes a while, and for some reason ḟinding the input's index in that list takes 20+ seconds. As such, the above link will probably time out.
             ḟ    # Find the index of the input in
  9↔              # Combinations of length 9 of
2ʀ                # [0, 1, 2] 
    µ ;           # Sorted by
     ∑            # their sum
           İ      # Index into
       «+⅛«       # "o x"
            Ṡ     # And concatenate
              bṅ  # Convert the index to binary and concatenate
                Ḣ # And remove the first character


C (clang), 163 133 130 bytes
i,j,c,o,p,g;f(*a){for(i=c=1;c;){for(g=o=p=9,j=i++;p--;j/=3)o-=j%3,g&=a[p]=="x o"[j%3];c+=o*o==o;for(p=g*13;p--;c/=2)a[p]=48+c%2;}}

Try it online!
-33 bytes thanks to @emanresu A
Ungolfed:
void func(int* a) {
    int c = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<19682; i++) {
        int g = 1;
        int o = 9;
        int j = i;
        for (int p = 9; p--; j /= 3) {
            // Subtract the position (X or O) from o
            o -= j % 3;

            // Check if the current cell matches the input
            g &= a[p] == "x o"[j % 3];
        }

        // If the entire board matches (g == 1), generate the 13-bit binary of c
        for(int p = g * 13; p--; c /= 2) {
            a[p] = 48 + c % 2;
        }

        // increment c if o is 0 or 1
        c += o * o == o;
    }
}


133 with a lot of stuff rewritten

@emanresu Very nice!

mildly cursed 130, might be a byte or two to save (yes the indexing's off by two, still works fine though)

Perl 5 -n, 97 bytes
$i=$_;$n=0;y/123/ ox/==9&&(s/x/x/g- s/o/o/g)=~/0|^1/&&++$n&&/$i/&&printf"%013b\n",$n for 1e8..4e8

Try it online!
Very slow as it loops from 100 000 000 to 400 000 000 (base-10) throwing away all numbers containing any other digits than 1s, 2s and 3s by checking if y/123/ ox/ returns 9 for the number of chars replaced where it translates 1 2 3 into   o x accordingly. Then where the count of xs is the same as or one more than the count of os the counter variable $n is increased by one since this is a valid input. When the now translated string of nine  , o or xs equals the input string, it outputs the 13 digit binary representation of the current $n.
Perl 5, 142 bytes
sub{local($_,$n)=$"x9;do{(s/x/x/g- s/o/o/g)!~/0|^1/ or$f{$_}=sprintf"%013b",$n++}while s/([ o])x*$/($1eq$"?o:x).($"x(-1+length$&))/e;$f{+pop}}

Try it online!
Second answer. This function gives each of the 6045 valid input strings a unique identifier with 13 bits in the hashmap %f and return those 13 bits (as a string of 0s and 1s) for all valid input strings of length 9 consisting of the three charachters  , o and x where the number of xs is the same or one more than the number of os. I chose to include the empty input of nine  s which returns thirteen 0s and this adds one more to the count of valid inputs: 6046 as I think the challenge wasn't clear about the all space input.

You right about 6046, I forgot empty board. I edited the question.

K (ngn/k), 22 bytes
As suggested by emanresu A, a port of their Vyxal answer ends up a lot shorter:
1_2\"o x"[+3\<+/!9#3]?

Try it online!

K (ngn/k), 33 31 bytes
(13#2)\"x o"[+3\&~-2!+/1-!9#3]?

Try it online!
+3\&~-2!+/1-!9#3 generates all valid boards using 0 for x, 1 for spaces and 2 for o. "x o"[...] converts the boards to strings, ? finds the argument in the list of strings and (13#2)\ converts the integer to 13 binary digits.

I don't know K that well so there's probably a byte or two to be saved here, but here's 25 based on my vyxal: 1_2\"o x"[v@<+/+v:+!9#3]?

Charcoal, 32 bytes
Ｐ×¹³0⮌⍘⌕ΦＥＸ³χ◧⍘ι xo⁹¬÷⁻№ιx№ιo²Ｓ²

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｐ×¹³0

Place 13 0s on the canvas so that the bits can be output LSB first thus avoiding having to manually pad them to length 13.
ＥＸ³χ◧⍘ι xo⁹

Generate all 3×3 boards of spaces, xs and os. (Some spurious "boards" are also generated but they will never match the input.)
Φ...¬÷⁻№ιx№ιo²

Filter on those where the count of xs minus the count of os is zero or one.
⮌⍘⌕...Ｓ²

Find the index of the input string and convert that to binary, LSB first.

JavaScript (Node.js), 100 bytes
s=>(i=1e4,g=(p,c)=>p[8]?i+=c&6?0:p<s:[0,7,1].map(n=>g(p+' xo'[n%5],~~c+n))|i)``.toString(2).slice(1)

Try it online!
Input a string, output 13 char 0-1 string.

JavaScript (Node.js), 77 bytes
s=>(i=0,g=(p,c)=>p[8]?i+=c&6?0:p<s:[0,7,1].map(n=>g(p+' xo'[n%5],~~c+n))|i)``

Try it online!
Input string as format 'x   oxx o', output an integer in range \$\left[0,6105\right]\$.

We encoded all 6046 valid boards together with another 59 invalid ones into number not greater than 6105. The bit string output version also added an extra 1808 to each output so they actually encoded in range \$\left[1808, 7913\right]\$.

Sorry but other contestant spent bytes to convert integer to string, so it will be unfair to them if you skip that part.

JavaScript (ES6), 104 bytes
Expects a 9-character string made of ' ', 'O', 'X' and returns a 13-character binary string.
s=>(g=k=>i--?g(k/b|0)+"01O X"[t-=~-(k%=b),k+6%~b]:t="")((F=n=>g(n,i=9)!=s&&!t+!~t+F(-~n))(b=3),i=13,b=2)

Try it online!

JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes
Expects a 9-character string made of ' ', 'O', 'X' and returns an integer in \$[0\dots6045]\$.
f=(s,n)=>(g=k=>i--?g(k/3|0)+"O X"[t-=~-(k%=3),k]:t="")(n,i=9)!=s&&!t+!~t+f(s,-~n)

Try it online!

It suppose this fails the requirement saying "It should return a string consisting of exactly 13 symbols,". I guess you need to convert this integer to binary then

@lvo I still hope that the output format will be relaxed, but I've added another version doing that.

Haskell, 177 bytes
e s t=take t.g.d where d a=divMod a$l s;g(a,b)=s!!b:g(d a)
f=filter
l=length
o g f=(.g).f.g
a s=e"01"13.l.f(\u->o((o(\c->l.f(==c)$u)(-)'x''o')==)(||)1 0&&u<s)$e"ox "9<$>[0..3^9]

Try it online!
Brute force.

Generate all base 3 strings of length 9 using the alphabet "ox "
e"ox "9<$>[0..3^9]

Count how many valid base 3 strings input is greater than
l.f(\u->o((o(\c->l.f(==c)$u)(-)'x''o')==)(||)1 0&&u<s)$

Encode the result as a base 2 string using the alphabet "01"
e"01"13.



You might be interested in the haskell golfing library

Ruby, 114 bytes
Brute-force solution. Iterates over all numbers in base 3, transliterates each to o/x/space, then if it’s a valid position increments a counter, breaking and returning the count in binary if it’s equal to the input.
->s{i=j=0
(t=("%9d"%j.to_s(3)).tr"012"," xo"
i+=1if(0..1)===t.count(?x)-t.count(?o)
j+=1)until s==t
"%013b"%(i-1)}

Attempt This Online!
Ruby, 104 bytes
Returns an integer rather than a binary string.
->s{i=j=0
(t=("%9d"%j.to_s(3)).tr"012"," xo"
i+=1if(0..1)===t.count(?x)-t.count(?o)
j+=1)until s==t
i-1}

Attempt This Online!

Python 3, 121 bytes
lambda s:bin(g('').index(s)+8888)[3:];g=lambda p,c=0:[p]*(c%8<2)if p[8:]else sum([g(p+' xo'[n%5],c+n)for n in[0,7,1]],[])

Try it online!
Python port to my JS solution.

Python 3, 115 bytes
lambda s:bin([str(i).translate([32,120,111]*88)for i in rang(10**9)if{*str(i)}<={*"189"}!=i%9<2].index(s)*7)[-13:]

Try it online!
A very slow solution. The range is replaced by a customized implementation in tio link to speed it up. It loops every (decimal) number less than 109, and only keeps numbers that is only composed with digits 1, 8, 9 and mod 9 less than 2. Then replace 1, 8, 9 by x, o,  . And all these strings are considered valid and assign an encoding to it from 0 to 9348. Then multiply the encoding by 7 and mod by 213.

Jelly, 16 bytes
3ṗ9SÞị“o x”iµBḊV

Try it online! Port of my Vyxal, see that for an explanation of why this works.
           i     # Find the index of the input in
 ṗ               # All combinations of
3                # 1...3
  9              # of length 9
    Þ            # Sorted by
   S             # their sums
     ị           # Index each value into
      “o x”      # "o x"
            µB   # Convert to binary
              ḊV # Remove first digit and concatenate


Python 3.8 (pre-release), 177 173 166 bytes
lambda s:f"{(t:=bin((L:=[f'{t:<9}'for i in range(3**9)if(t:=g(i)[:-1]).count('x')-t.count('o')in(0,1)]).index(s))[2:]):0>13}"
g=lambda x:'1'*(x<1)or' xo'[x%3]+g(x//3)

Try it online!
-11 bytes thanks to Malo
Basically brute force, converts base 3 to ' xo' strings and then enumerates cases where there are 0 or 1 more x's than o's. Also accounts for extra whitespace/zeros at the end of each string.
Ungolfed:
def f(s):
    L=[]
    g=lambda x:'1'*(x<1)or' xo'[x%3]+g(x//3)
    for i in range(3**9):
        t1=g(i)[:-1]
        if t1.count('x')-t1.count('o') in (0,1):L.append(t1+' '*(9-len(t1)))
    t1=bin(L.index(s))[2:]
    return '0'*(13-len(t1))+t1


You can use f string formatting : f"{t1:0>13}" instead of '0'*(13-len(t1))+t1
---> [https://tio.run/##TY9BjsIwDEX3cwoLCdkuFAjZQEQ5wdygdFGGpkSCpApBCkKcvROgjOZ58y3Z/t/dLRydlavO97rY9af6vD/UcFF6dKegir2xRN@qKMMEATNa56fGUmDWzoMBY8HXtm1IZtmajX6utGS4VLmoePbjrjYQRuQ8fBqHnG4upoLTgLGHJtKFuVyqitViK@Rj9NUWQ4yoUCTTuBHsPEJ0WMaxrCYtxflccv8XInk8cQmcYnRD/dPw1vAiaYChe@kBZNV5k1Lq9AP3vw Try it online!]

Thanks! I've never seen that use of string formatting before.

You can also use thos way of formatting and replace t1' '*(9-len(t)) with f'{t:<9}' --- total 166 bytes ---> [https://tio.run/##TY9BbgIxDEX3PYWFVNkeoJBmAxbTE3CD6SyGQqaRIBmFVEqFOHsIdFr1efO/9OVvD9/x0zu9GkI29Xs@dqfdvoOzmMmFotQ764i2UjcGL1E26ysaH8CCdRA61x9IV9Warblne7LcyFy1/PLhv1wkTMjz@Gs8clm2nCkuAev2h0Rn5uZVWpblm9LXyVNfj/1JUGFFaaPYB4TksUnPup32lBYLzfnviNJxxxdwhsmP80/Dj4YHRQOM7qFHkGUItlxpyg@cc74B Try it online!]
